# when to sum two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I have typist A who makes errors with rate a errors/page, and B who makes with b errors/page. Now each of em write half of the full publication. I know both are Poisson random variables. In this perspective, how do I know when to add/subtract two random variables? Are there any specific conditions, or it is just an art?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the publication is typed by both of them, the number of errors remains the average of a and b.

Comment: Ok. Can you make out of it a case, when we have to add them only.i.e. A+B is the resultant random variable.

Comment: A types a 1-page publication; B does the same. Then the total is a+b.

Answer (score 0):

Both typists independently make errors within the publication at a known average rate, with each error independent of the placement of other errors (Poisson Distribution).  Thus, other than which half of the publication they occur, the errors made within the publication will be independent of the placement of other errors and be made at an average rate(per publication) that is the sum of the twain (again, a Poisson distribution).

To be clear.   Suppose the publication is $2n$ pages long, and each writes $n$ pages.   Then if the first makes an average of $na$ errors per publication, and the second makes an average of $nb$ errors per publication, then the total errors per the publication is Poisson distributed with mean of $n(a+b)$ errors.

Comment: So, that means the total rate in the question's case is not (a+b)/2 but a+b. Right?

Comment: @IsamAbdullah If the publication contains *two* pages it would be $(a+b)$.  If the publication contains *one* page and they each type an half, then it would be $(a+b)/2$.  How many pages are in the publication?

Comment: @ Graham. I can't follow this. What my mind tells me is, it will be always average. If there are two pages, One is written by me with rate a errors/page, other by you at b errors/page, then I can't understand that per page rate can be a+b in any way, it always gotta be less than $a+b$. What do you say?

Comment: per *publication*, not per page.

Comment: both can't type at the same time.. Right?